# how to import the Cryptographic library in asp.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net5

hello I have the following drawback, it turns out that in my code I have the following:

```
private void CreatePasswordCreate(string password, out byte[] passwordCreate, out byte[] passwordRepeat) {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
        { 
            passwordCreate = hmac.Key;
            passwordRepeat = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }
```

but when writing it I get the following error:

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Invoices.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What was previously shown appears to me in the following line of code specifically in the word 'Security'

```
using (var hmac = new System.Security.Crytography.HMACSHA512())
```

and I also get the following error:

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Text' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Invoices.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I get this error in the following line of code:

```
passwordRepeat = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
```

I do not know how to import this library since I am a newbie in this, I would like to know how to add this library or what content the class 'Security' and 'Text' should have, and where it should go is it created since it does not appear automatically added in it

```
using System
```

Comment: Are you familiar with nuget? Being a newbie is no shame; but I wouldn't start with security- related development.

Comment: Yes, but if I do not start now, when? If not, I will never learn, I go here for solutions, not for them to return me to the beginning, a help would not teach me a bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the error I had with the following
instead of the code that had the solution is this

```
private void CreatePasswordCreate(string password, out byte[] passwordCreate, out byte[] passwordRepeat)
    {
        using (var hmac = new Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
        {
            passwordRepeat = hmac.Key;
            passwordCreate = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }
```

and then make the call of the function that was created before the assignment of the variables in the following way

```
CreatePasswordCreate(model.password,out byte[] passwordCreate, out byte[] passwordRepeat );
```

and importing `using System.Text;`

however it also works in the following way, adding the system in Cryptography

```
private void CreatePasswordCreate(string password, out byte[] passwordCreate, out byte[] passwordRepeat)
    {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
        {
            passwordRepeat = hmac.Key;
            passwordCreate = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }
```